# WMS with EPSG:3004 not returning tiles in LeafletJS

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, wms, proj4leaflet

I am consuming an [Italian WMS](http://maps1.insula.it/common/cache/ramses/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities) in a CRS with an [EPSG code of 3004](https://epsg.io/3004) in QGIS. It works somehow (Needed to change the CRS from 4326 to 3004), yet the definition in the GetCapabilities document is strange (states to be 4326 but uses coordinates in projected CRS).

I am now trying to create a webmap with the same WMS using leaflet and Proj4leaflet. All the network traffic towards the WMS returns 500 as status codes:

Example URL:

http://maps1.insula.it/common/cache/ramses/?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=ramses&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=false&version=1.1.1&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG%3A3004&bbox=2312320.0789986267,5034917.271996673,2312448.078998631,5035045.271996661

If I replace the BBOX coordinates with a BBOX from QGIS it returns an image:

http://maps1.insula.it/common/cache/ramses/?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=ramses&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=false&version=1.1.1&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG%3A3004&bbox=2310927.24273836985230446,5034502.11386785749346018,2311008.92086785659193993,5034583.79199734423309565

The bbox of the WMS is defined as:

2288384.0789999999105930,5011877.2719999998807907 : 2336386.6389999999664724,5057879.8320000004023314

Here is the non-working [codepen](https://codepen.io/butcher/pen/XWmazaP). The releant part is this definition:

```
    var crs = new L.Proj.CRS("EPSG:3004", "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9996 +x_0=2520000 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs",
    {
        resolutions: [
            8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128,
            64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5
        ]
    }),
    map = new L.Map('map', {
        crs: crs,
    });

  L.tileLayer.wms('http://maps1.insula.it/common/cache/ramses/', {
    layers: 'ramses',
    format: 'image/png',
    maxZoom: 14,
  minZoom: 0,
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Please include relevant part of nonworking code in the body of the question, otherwise it will most likely to be closed as not being conformant with this site policy.

Comment: I've included the relevant snippet from codepen

Comment: So the WMS itself definitely has some issues, because bounding boxes must express coordinates in the CRS they reference and the ramses layer has `<BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:4326" minx="2288384.079000" miny="5011877.272000" maxx="2336386.639000" maxy="5057879.832000"/>`  so it does indeed look like the data is not EPSG:4326

Comment: There is nothing syntactically different between the two requests, only the precision of the BBOX coordinates.   The service does not state that the layers are not subsetable, or resizeable, so it is not an error (by my reading of the WMS 1.1.1 specification) to request any bounding box.  Therefore you should not be getting a 500 error here.  This looks like a server issue, and trying to code around it will be problematic

Comment: But interesting question is how does then QGIS know how to construct the right bounding box?

Comment: I needed to change crs in QIS to 3004. it was defaulted to 4326 as it is mentioned in the getCapabilities .